# Chromatic Number, independent edges of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph with vertex set $V=\{1,2,\dots,2005\}$. Two distinct vertices $i,j\in V$ are adjacent iff $i+j\equiv1\pmod{3}$.

What is the chromatic number and independent edges?

Comment: Is $2$ adjacent to itself?

Comment: no, two different vertices must necessary

Comment: So you want the chromatic number, but what are you counting or to find in "independent edges"? When are two edges said to be independent?

Comment: independent edges are no two of which are adjacent.

Comment: So, are you looking for the size of the ***largest*** set of pairwise independent edges, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide your vertices into three classes:
$$
V_0=\text{all vertices whose labels are congruent to }0\pmod3\\
V_1=\text{all vertices whose labels are congruent to }1\pmod3\\
V_2=\text{all vertices whose labels are congruent to }2\pmod3.
$$

Then the graph on $V_0$ and $V_1$ will be a complete bipartite graph and $V_2$ will be a clique. There will be no edges from $V_2$ to either $V_0$ or $V_1$.

Thus the chromatic number is the order of the clique on $V_2$ and the size of a maximal set of independent edges $M$ will be the size of the maximal matching between $V_0$ and $V_1$ plus the size of the maximal matching in the clique on $V_2$. Thus
$$
\lvert M\rvert= \min\{\lvert V_0\rvert,~\lvert V_1\rvert\}+\left\lfloor \left\lvert \frac{V_2}{2}\right\rvert\right\rfloor.
$$

Comment: In normal usage, two edges are *adjacent* if they are both incident with a common vertex (just as two vertices are *adjacent* if they are both incident with a common edge), and two edges are *independent* if they are not adjacent. There will be lots of independent edges.

Comment: Ah, then the size of a maximal set of independent edges will be the size of the maximal matching between $V_0$ and $V_1$ plus the size of the maximal matching in the clique on $V_2$.